# Read Controller variables on js.erb on AJAX request on Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

im having problems making a response from an AJAX request. What im trying to do is use the controller variable on the js.erb file.

I reduced the logic to this

testcontroller.rb

```
def test
  @test = "some value"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js 
  end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= button_tag "test button", type: 'button', id: 'testbutton' %>
$("#testbutton").on("click", function() {
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "/ajax/test",
  dataType: "script",
  });
});
```

routes.rb

```
post 'ajax/test' => 'testcontroller#test'
```

test.js.erb

```
alert("<%= @test %>");
```

I get an empty alert

[image]

Where did i go wrong?

---

EDIT - SOLVED

The 'test' method was below (but not inside, I double check it) the private methods of the controller class. When I put it above, it worked normal.

Anyways, thank you all for your time.

Comment: Something to try: change your AJAX request to not set the `contentType` and` dataType` and see if that works. If it still does't, leave those unset, but change the `url` to "/ajax/test.js" - sometimes you need to explicitly set the .js to make sure the right content type is set (which probably should be `application/javascript` anyway).

Comment: I copied everything as you provided, and it worked for me. Based on what you received, it seems that `@test` doesn't equal anything. Add `<% puts @test, "a" %>` to your `test.js.erb` and see if you see them in your server console.

Comment: @MrDanA, i get the same result.

Comment: @Clark, i get an "a" and nothing more apart from the normal console output

Comment: Okay, somehow `@test` is getting set to `nil` or "". Try `<% puts @test.class %>` If you see `String` in the console `@test` is set to "", if it is `nil` `@test` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code that you have shown is correct. You may need to restart your server or you may have some duplication. Do you have more than one `TestController`?

Also, `post 'ajax/test' => 'testcontroller#test'` should be `post 'ajax/test' => 'test_controller#test'` It should be named `TestController`.

In addition, a better way to inject the JS is to use `alert("<%= j @test.html_safe %>");`